# How to count percentage for monthly input money for 4 years?

Tags: percentages

In every month, we put ex.: `20 000` "money" to the bank = `240 000` yearly.

In every year the goverment gives `72 000` "money" to our bank account.

This goes for 4 years = (`4 * 12 * 20 000`) + (`4 * 72 000`) = `960 000 + 288 000 = 1 248 000`

In the end, we will get: `1 248 000`

**The big questionHow can I count that how much "profit percentage" did I get from this per year?**

If I try (**BAD!**), then:

- In 4 year I put in `4 * 12 * 20 000 = 960 000`
- At the end I got back = `1 248 000`
- So the profit for 4 years look like: `1 248 000 - 960 000 = 288 000`
- So `288 000` is the 30% of `960 000` for 4 years. But I want it yearly.
- So `30% / 4 = 7,5%` **yearly profit?**

Lets reverse count to make sure:

- First year, I put in `12 * 20 000 = 240 000`, so `240 000 * 1,075 = 258 000`
- Second year, I already have `258 000` + current year put in `240 000`, so `498 000 * 1,075 = 535 350`
- Third year, I already have `535 350` + current year put in `240 000`, so `775 350 * 1,075 = 833 501`
- Fourth year, I already have `833 501` + current year put in `240 000`, so `1 073 501 * 1,075 = 1 154 013` .. this is not `1 248 000`... what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

7.5 is not so far off.

If you want to calculate percent per year if we pretend it is a fixed interest rate then it is

$$\sqrt[4]{\frac{(240000+72000)\times 4}{240000\times 4}}=1.0678$$

or 6.78%, quite close to 7.5%

It's gonna be lower every year since it is fixed amount of money.

---

That your approximation almost works can be explained by Taylor expanding for example $(1+k)^x$ to linear equation (first order polynomial) for small values of $k$.

Comment: wow, thx, but I counted 4 years with 7.5% and got 1 154 013, less than 1 248 000. How can less percentage be good if 7.5% is smaller already than 1 248 000? what am I missing?

Comment: can you please correct me if I am wrong? :) or anybody else? Many thanks

Comment: Sorry I have forgotten how to explain things like this. You want to check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series and geometric sum. I can maybe write a better answer later after work.